# Do CSS class names have any effect on SEO?

Tags: seo, html, css

I have seen some of our competitors using keyword-rich CSS class names. As an example, if I were in the pet grooming business, I would name my `#menu` as:

```css
#menu.pet.grooming.moreKeywords.etc { ... }
```

Does this have any effect on SEO? If so, what is the best practice?

Comment: Branding and SEO seem to have gotten mixed together. I'd say that is branding, not SEO. It's still valuable, but probably won't help page rankings in the major search engines.

Comment: See also: [Is minifying id and class names a bad SEO practice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25470/is-minifying-id-and-class-names-a-bad-seo-practice)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google says nothing about that.
The more important things are **page structure** (correct tags, H1 for headers, SECTION for sections, etc..), and also **metatags** and **urls**.

Google will give visibility to sites that **loads fast**, have good document structure and descriptive urls.
You should focus on that.

More info here:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely 100% NOT!

It's a good rule to make your CSS classes useful and descriptive for a human to read...but what you're seeing here is probably just this; good naming conventions. If your competitor believes that this will help with SEO then they are mistaken.

Instead, focus on good 'in page' content, descriptive titles and useful meta tags.

Avoid keyword stuffing and spamming; it will get you nowhere fast.

Good luck, Michael.

Answer (score 10):

**Answer**: Do not use custom CSS class names for SEO benefits.

Many modern search engines will not be looking for keywords within your tags - imagine the miniscule percentage of websites that actually customize their tags to cater for search engines and how much unnecessary work would be required to implement tag-crawling as a result.

Instead, make sure to use standard tag names such as `a`, `ul` as much as you can without having to result to CSS tricks. These will make your site much easier to crawl, indexing many more pages as a result. Make sure to use heading tags `(h1, h2 ... hn)` as much as possible over custom CSS font tags as search engines will make sure to emphasize these results later.

Answer (score 9):

No. The general rule is things that affect SEO are things that will affect the users experience on the page. Class names do not, in fact they could even slow it down, google recommend short class names

Answer (score 4):

As per your question answer is A Big No!!

CSS is part of website designing and present your website. in some cases, website design is affecting SEO like image quality, Domain name, Title, meta description and some other factors.

CSS class name never affects any factor of SEO. Because a class name is only to identify a particular section of designing. The class name can be used by CSS and JavaScript to perform certain tasks for elements with the specified class name.

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer is no!

your content, content structure, HTML tags (H1 - H6) and HTML TITLE tag are the ones that have an influence. Read [HTML Elements Best Practices](https://quoracreative.com/article/H1-To-H6-HTML-Elements-Best-Practices-For-Titles-And-Headings)

Along with, It is nowhere mentioned in Google Guidelines so ill say it is a myth and you should concentrate on other aspects of SEO. Hope this helps.