# Can randomly named CSS classes hurt rankings?

Tags: seo, css, google-ranking

My website uses random words for CSS classes.  For example: `gruig`.

Now I'm little scared that this might somehow lower our Google rankings.  Will it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is minifying id and class names a bad SEO practice?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25470/is-minifying-id-and-class-names-a-bad-seo-practice)

Comment: "**random** words"?! You should use words that make _development_ easier.

Comment: I do not believe that this is a duplicate of [Is minifying id and class names a bad SEO practice?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25470/is-minifying-id-and-class-names-a-bad-seo-practice) as some have suggested.   This question has nothing to do with minified code, just code with randomly chosen names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google says nothing about that. So it's ok. But, you should minify your css because it's good practice to optimize your CSS code to make your website faster by decreasing the file size.

Answer (score 3):

No search engine cares one whit about your class names and such things are given no SEO consideration in any way, shape or form. They serve no purpose as far as content goes. They mean nothing to the end user.